# Using ajax with a while statement and DB

Tags: php, ajax

I have a question about using ajax.I want to delete something of my screen (to be clear, some articles)  I'm generating content (the articles) on the screen with this code:

```
while($test = $allArticles->fetch_assoc())
{   
        echo "<div class='metfoto'>";
        echo "<h1 name='tt' class='titelopmaak'>".$test['titel'] . "<br /></h1>";
    echo "<p class='artikelopmaak'>" . $test['article'] . "</p>";
        echo "<form method='post' action=''>";
    echo "<input type='submit' class='delete' name='verwijder' value='verwijder'>";
        echo "</form>";
    //echo "<h1>".$test['id']."</h1>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

This all is working very well without ajax.  But I want to make this(the delete with the button) happen without a page refresh. 
When i for example check the content of $test['id'], i receive one number. **My problem with the code below is that when i want to put the title into variabel (var titel) for ajax, it loads all the titels from my page.**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".delete").click(function(){
                    var titel = $(".titelopmaak").text();
                    var artikel = $(".artikelopmaak").text();

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "assets/ajax/deleteArticle.php",
            data: { titelA:titel },

        }).done(function( msg ) {

            if(msg.status != "error")

                {
                    if(msg.status == "success")
                    {
                        $(".titelopmaak").fadeOut();

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }

        });
        return false;
    })

});             
        </script>
```

**EDIT**

**I hope i explained my question in a better way now**

Comment: To summarize your question: *"I have a question about using ajax, please read all my code and then tell me what I am doing wrong."* - please improve your style of asking a question, what specifically do you want to know?

Comment: @Hakre, i'm really sorry, i understand it is difficult for you to understand what i mean without knowing the story. See my edit please.

Comment: knowing the story is almost irrelevant @NielsJansen. you need to put some effort into simlifying your problem to a concise issue instead of making it a wall of code that you're expecting others to happily read to try and find a question in it. At best you have several questions that are related - and they should be asked individually.

Comment: If iniciases the post with the edited paragraph, maybe I read the post until the end. Is better a short question and concise that a poem of code

Comment: ok sorry guys, i will take all your feedback into account for the next time.. i promise... But for me it's difficult to post the right code, and the right question to be helped the best way...  At this moment I don't know what to change to this post to make it better for you guys. I'm sorry..

Comment: try this template: "here's some **short** code, with this input I expect it to do this, but it does that"

Comment: @AD7six I changed my question and code, is this better?

Comment: In deleteArticle.php, have you mentioned that the function deleteArticle() is to be called when the ajax function invokes deleteArticle.php

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here

```
 var titel = $(".titelopmaak").text();
```

You get all the values ​​of the elements with class `.titelopmaak` but you only need one.

This is the correct one, we go up the tree and then find the item.

```
var titel = $(this).closest('.metfoto').find('.titelopmaak').text();
```

But, control elements by the title its very bad practice, use id instead of.

```
<script>
$(document).ready( function(){
    $('.delete').submit( function() {
            $.ajax({
                url:    $(this).attr('action'),
                data:   $(this).serialize(),
                type:   $(this).attr('method'),
                success: function(data, status, jqXHR) {
                        $(".titelopmaak").fadeOut();
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                }
            );
    });
});
</script>
<? while($test = $allArticles->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
<form method="POST" action="" class="delete">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?=$test['id']?>" name="delete">
    <input type="submit" value='verwijder'>
</form>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: when i alert the var titel, the variable is empty. so there is nothing posted in

Comment: Tested it on jquery 1.7.2 to your code, it works, try opening it with a debugger, firebug or something.

Comment: I trying to recapilute everything and rebuilding it WITHOUT ajax because, everything was messed up. So for everybody, my problem now is that when i hit the delete button, nothing happend, i mean, for exame i say, delete from tbl ... where id = 5, when i click delete somewhere, nothing happens, but in de DB the content with ID 5 is gone, when i do a page refresh, the content on the screen is also gone. I thought it would work also at runtime ( i mean with pagerefresh automatic) without ajax...

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this....

You have to specify individual id for each html elements

```
while($test = $allArticles->fetch_assoc())
{   
     $cid = $test['id'];
        echo "<div id='div$cid' class='metfoto'>";
        echo "<h1 name='tt' id='h1$cid' class='titelopmaak'>".$test['titel'] . "<br /></h1>";
    echo "<p id='para$cid' class='artikelopmaak'>" . $test['article'] . "</p>";
    echo "<input type='submit' class='delete' name='verwijder' id='verwijder$cid' onclick='deleteValue($cid);' value='verwijder'>";
    echo "</div>";
}
```

javascript function

Refer the h1 and div by their ids.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function deleteValue(cid)
{
         var titel = $("#h1"+cid).text();
         var artikel = $("#para"+cid).text();

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "assets/ajax/deleteArticle.php",
            data: { titelA:titel },

        }).done(function( msg ) {

            if(msg.status != "error")

                {
                    if(msg.status == "success")
                    {
                        $("#h1"+cid).fadeOut();

                    }
                    else
                    {

                    }
                }

        });
        return false;
    })

}
</script>
```

deleteArticle.php

```
include "connection.php";
$title = $_POST['titelA'];
$ok = mysql_query("delete from yourtable where title='$title');
echo "your msg here";
```

Comment: cid is not defined
[abord]  

var titel = $("#h1"+cid).text();

Comment: Sorry I have missed a single quote at the end of onclick...onclick='deleteValue($cid);'. Does $test['id'] exists or not?